# getUserMedia image capture resolution vs. html video element size

Tags: javascript, getusermedia

Is there a way to capture a higher resolution image than the actual width of my onscreen video element which is showing my webcam image that I intend to capture?

Currently, I have set the width in getUserMedia to 1280, but my  element is constrained to 640px. I'd like to still be storing images of 1280px wide so that I'm getting higher quality images.

Code:

```
<div id="video-container">
    <h3 id="webcam-title">Add Photos</h3>
        <video id="video" autoplay playsinline></video>
    <select id="videoSource"></select>
    <div id="take-photo-button" onclick="takeSnapshot();">TAKE PHOTO <div class="overlay"></div></div>
    <canvas  id="myCanvas" style="display:none;"></canvas>
    <div id="snapshot-container"></div>

    <div id="approval-form-submit">SAVE ORDER</div>
</div>


<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        var videoSelect = document.querySelector('select#videoSource');
        var initialized = false;

        //Obtain media object from any browser
        navigator.getUserMedia = (  navigator.getUserMedia ||
                                    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                                    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                                    navigator.msGetUserMedia);

        var video_height, snapshot_height;

        //var video_width = 1280;
        var video_width = 640;
        var container_width = 800;
        var snapshot_margin = 10;
        var snapshot_width = (container_width - snapshot_margin*6)/3;
        //var snapshot_width = 1280;

        function fillSelectWithDevices(deviceInfos) {
            var value = videoSelect.value;
            $(videoSelect).empty();

            for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
                var deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
                if (deviceInfo.kind === 'videoinput') {
                    var option = document.createElement('option');
                    option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
                    option.text = deviceInfo.label || `camera ${videoSelect.length + 1}`;
                    videoSelect.appendChild(option);
                    if(!initialized && deviceInfo.label==='Back Camera'){
                        value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
                        initialized = true;
                    }
                }
                if (Array.prototype.slice.call(videoSelect.childNodes).some(n => n.value === value)) { 
                    videoSelect.value = value;
                }    
            }
        }

        function gotStream(stream) {
            window.stream = stream; // make stream available to console
            video.srcObject = stream;

            video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev){

                video_height = video.videoHeight * (video_width/video.videoWidth);
                snapshot_height = video.videoHeight * (snapshot_width/video.videoWidth);

                initCanvas();

                // Firefox currently has a bug where the height can't be read from
                // the video, so we will make assumptions if this happens.

                if (isNaN(video_height)) {
                  video_height = video_width * (3/4);
                  console.log("Can't read video height. Assuming 4:3 aspect ratio");
                }

                //video_width=640;
                //video_height=480;

                video.setAttribute('width', video_width);
                video.setAttribute('height', video_height);
                canvas.setAttribute('width', video_width);
                canvas.setAttribute('height', video_height);

            }, false);


            return navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
        }

        function handleError(error) {
            console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
        }

        function start() {
            if (window.stream) {
                window.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => {
                    track.stop();
                });
            }
            var videoSource = videoSelect.value;
            var constraints = {
                video: {deviceId: videoSource ? {exact: videoSource} : undefined,
                        facingMode: "environment",
                        width:1280},
                audio: false
            };
            navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(gotStream).then(fillSelectWithDevices).catch(handleError);
        }

        videoSelect.onchange = start;
        start();

        var canvas, ctx, container;

        function initCanvas() {
          canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
          ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          container = document.getElementById("snapshot-container");

          //Reconstitute snapshots from form URI after failed submit
          var image_list_field = $('#image-list-field'),
            URI_array = image_list_field.val().split(','),
            dataURI;
          for(var i = 0;i<URI_array.length;i++){
            if(URI_array[i]){
                dataURI = "data:image/png;base64,"+URI_array[i];
                displaySnapshot(dataURI);
            }
          }
        }


        // Capture a photo by fetching the current contents of the video
        // and drawing it into a canvas, then converting that to a PNG
        // format data URL. By drawing it on an offscreen canvas and then
        // drawing that to the screen, we can change its size and/or apply
        // other changes before drawing it.
        takeSnapshot = function() {
            alert (video_width + " " + video_height);
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video_width, video_height);
            var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            displaySnapshot(data);
        }

        function displaySnapshot(data){
            var photo = document.createElement('img'),
                snapshot_div = document.createElement('div'),
                delete_text = document.createElement('p');

            photo.setAttribute('src', data);

            $(photo).css({"width":snapshot_width+"px"});
            $(photo).addClass("snapshot-img");
            $(snapshot_div).css({"width":snapshot_width+"px","height":snapshot_height+25+"px"});
            $(delete_text).text("Delete Photo");
            $(snapshot_div).append(photo).append(delete_text);
            $(delete_text).on('click',function(){$(this).closest('div').remove()})
            container.append(snapshot_div);
        }

        $('#approval-form-submit').on('click',function(e){
            var form = $('#approval-form'),
                image_list_field = $('#image-list-field'),
                imageURI;
            image_list_field.val("");
            $('.snapshot-img').each(function(i, d){
                imageURI = d.src.split(',')[1]+',';
                image_list_field.val(image_list_field.val()+imageURI);
            });
            form.submit();
        })
```